# Negative heights when converting SRTM data

Tags: c++, c, file, binaryfiles

I want to get the height for a certain latitude/longitude pair from the NASA SRTM dataset (http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/SRTM3/Eurasia/).

As a starter I want to get all heights from a HGT file:

```
int totalPx = 1201; //3 degree
char buffer[2];
for (int i=0; i<totalPx; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<totalPx; j++)
    {
        int pos = (i * totalPx + j) * 2;

        m_openedFile.seek(pos); //m_openedFile is a Qt QFile
        m_openedFile.read(buffer, 2);
        short h = 0 | (buffer[0] << 8) | (buffer[1] << 0);
        if (h < 0)
            printf("%d", h);
    }
}
```

This seems to work for some coordinates (e.g. the height values look plausible) but there are also many negative height values.  How can I correctly read the SRTM/HGT file?

Regards,

Comment: Could it be below the sea level?

Comment: Try `buffer[0] | (buffer[1] << 8)`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. The problem is the signed char. ``ùnsigned char buffer[2];`` works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beware of sign extension when converting `char` to `int`

```
// char buffer[2];
unsigned char buffer[2];
short h = buffer[0] << 8 | buffer[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out: the problem was the signed char instead of the unsigned char which lead to the wrong bit shifts:

```
int totalPx = 1201; //3 degree
unsigned char buffer[2];
for (int i=0; i<totalPx; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<totalPx; j++)
    {
        int pos = (i * totalPx + j) * 2;

        m_openedFile.seek(pos); //m_openedFile is a Qt QFile
        m_openedFile.read(buffer, 2);
        short h = 0 | (buffer[0] << 8) | (buffer[1] << 0);
        if (h < 0)
            printf("%d", h);
    }
}
```